# Escaping imagemagick text input with apostrophes

Tags: imagemagick, imagemagick-convert

I'm drawing the text output from `display-dhammapada` to an existing image. The following CLI command works:

```
convert test.jpg 
    -pointsize 30 
    -draw "gravity northwest 
           fill black 
           text 120,200 '$( display-dhammapada)'" 
    result.png
```

...except when I receive a quote that has a contraction. Then the text input ends prematurely with an error such as:

```
convert: non-conforming drawing primitive definition `s' @ error/draw.c/DrawImage/3182
```

which was an apostrophe s case.

If I reverse the quotes from `" ' ' "` to `' " " '` then I end up with the literal text `$( display-dhammapada)` on my image.

What is the best way to sanitize my input in this case?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could sanitise your quote through `sed` like this:

```
convert -size 1000x1000 xc:red -pointsize 30 -draw "gravity northwest fill black text 120,200 '$(./display-dhammapada|sed "s/'/\\\'/g")'" result.png
```

*display-dhammapada*

```
#!/bin/bash
printf "There's one there!"
```

[image]

### FYI:

It may be an idea to write a general purpose sanitiser script that you can maintain and modify. You could consider not allowing it to pass `@` as the first character which would make ImageMagick read a file and could permit attacks and you may not want to allow various other things through - e.g. trailing newlines, or semi-colons.

Comment: Thank you. I also appreciate the tip about creating a more durable script. In this particular instance, your simple solution is enough.